# Multiple ServiceStack applications with one RabbitMQ server

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, servicestack

I have created 2 ServiceStack applications that run as Windows services via TopShelf and make use of one RabbitMQ server. Unfortunately when I start the second application the following exception occurs:

> Exception in Rabbit MQ Server: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - cannot redeclare exchange 'mx.servicestack.topic' in vhost '/' with different type, durable, internal or autodelete value"

The startup code contains the following code:

**App 1**

```
...
var rabbitMqServer = new RabbitMqServer();

rabbitMqServer.RegisterHandler<BusMessages.CrawlRequest>(
    n =>
    {
        var request = n.GetBody();
        this.Crawl(request);
        return null;
    });

rabbitMqServer.Start();
...
```

**App 2**

```
...
var rabbitMqServer = new RabbitMqServer();

rabbitMqServer.RegisterHandler<SendMailRequest>(
    message =>
    {
        SendMail(message.GetBody());
        return null;
    });

rabbitMqServer.Start();
...
```

The problem seems to be with the exchange named `mx.servicestack.topic`, which is defaulted by ServiceStack. Does anyone know a solution to circumvent this or change the Exchange name so I can use multiple (rather default) ServiceStack applications in combination with the same RabbitMQ server?

**Update**

As I was looking into it more deeply it seemed to be a bug in ServiceStack.RabbitMq v4.0.31 (used in App 1). In that version the default exchange `mx.servicestack.topic` is added as a `fanout` exchange type instead of a `topic` exchange type. App 2 was using ServiceStack.RabbitMq v4.0.40 which tries to add/use the exchange `mx.servicestack.topic` as a `topic` exchange type, as it should be. Upgrading the ServiceStack packages to version 4.0.40 for App 1 fixed this issue.

I prefer the way of segregation for different applications like Alain explains in his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31209330/1278669.
However, for different applications working in the same (small) customers' domain it's very doable to use the default exchanges like ServiceStack creates.

Last but not least, I found a dirty workaround to get App 2 running next to App 1 without upgrading the ServiceStack packages of App 1. That's done by doing the following:

```
...
QueueNames.ExchangeTopic = "mx.App2.topic";
var rabbitMqServer = new RabbitMqServer();
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need multiple vhosts in the RabbitMQ server to segregate your ServiceStack applications.

Instead of `amqp://localhost:5672` you can use `amqp://localhost:5672/vhostname` when configuring your **RabbitMqServer** as described here:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ

In a practical deployment the RabbitMQ server wouldn't be on localhost.  I'm using that above as a short step from where you currently are using the built-in default which is `amqp://localhost:5672` when invoking `new RabbitMqServer()`.

Virtual hosts need to be added on the RabbitMQ server ahead of time and users need to be created for them separately.  They are effectively separate AMQP servers with shared infrastructure.

You can add vhosts with [**rabbitmqctl**](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html) as follows

```
rabbitmqctl add-vhost vhostname
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as this is the proper way to segregate different applications. I also edited my question with an update section in which I explain how I fixed/prevented the exception that occurred.